# Can apache zookeeper be used as messages channel?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am new to apache zookeeper. I have a distributed application. Each node need to send messages (also heavy) to each other. Does anybody suggest to use Zookeeper as a messages exchange channel, or is it used only for collaboration ?

I hope I dont miss anything from the whole picture!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider posting your question to the [Zookeeper user list](http://zookeeper.apache.org/lists.html) for a more complete answer.  Heavy message passing is not a highly recommended use of Zookeeper.  Zookeeper is a coordination service, so it can help you manage where to send messages, or where specific destinations are located, but probably isn't the application for sending heavy messages between processes.